# List all files and directories with jcifs

Tags: java, samba, jcifs

I'm trying to list all files and directories from samba.
So I create a SmbFile :

```
SmbFile smb = new SmbFile("smb:\\\\10.0.4.3\\sharedFiles\\")
```

I am able to create new files, but I can not list files and directories.
I'm getting value 2 from `smb.getType()`, that means it is `TYPE_WORKGROUP`, so if I do `smb.listFiles()` I get all servers registered as members of a NetBIOS.
Does anyone know what I have to do to be able to get files and directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, finally I got it, here is the solution that worked for me:

```
SmbFile smb = new SmbFile("smb:\\\\10.0.4.3\\sharedFiles\\", "smb://10.0.4.3/sharedFiles/");
smb.listFiles(); // OK
```

And it lists all files, with no directories.